# Why can methods in Java 8 interfaces not be static and final?

Tags: java, java-8, static, final

Why can static methods in an interface in java 8 not be declared as final? What would the difference be by adding final?

Comment: Can you post an example of what's working and what's not? I don't fully get what you are asking...

Comment: They can be `static` since Java 9. Also making `static` methods `final` in interface is pointless since they are not inherited, for instance we can't use `List.of(...)` via `ArrayList.of(...)`.

Comment: @Pshemo interfaces allow `static` method since Java 8. The `private` methods are new in Java 9.

Comment: @Holger Woops, thank you for correction. I somehow connected it with introduction of collections factory methods like `List.of` but somehow forgot about many other static methods introduced with streams like `Comparator.comparing(...)`. Unfortunately I can't correct my previous comment so at least will upvote yours for better visibility. Again thank you.

Comment: @Pshemo well, the main point of your comment still is correct, `static` interface methods are not inherited, so `final` would be meaningless.